# Spark fails to read CSV when last column name contains spaces

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-commons, spark-csv

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Column One      | Column Two      | Column Three    |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| This is a value | This is a value | This is a value |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| This is a value | This is a value | This is a value |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| This is a value | This is a value | This is a value |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

In plain text, it actually looks like this:

```
Column One,Column Two,Column Three
This is a value,This is a value,This is a value
This is a value,This is a value,This is a value
This is a value,This is a value,This is a value
```

My `spark.read` method looks like this:

```
val df = spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .schema(schema)
    .option("quote", "\"")
    .option("escape", "\"")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    .load(inputFilePath)
```

When `multiLine` is set to `true`, the `df` loads as empty. It loads fine when `multiLine` is set to `false`, but I need `multiLine` set to `true`.

If I change the name of `Column Three` to `ColumnThree`, and also update that in the `schema` object, then it works fine. It seems like `multiLine` is being applied to the header row! I was hoping that wouldn't be the case when `header` is also set to `true`.

Any ideas how to get around this? Should I be using the `univocity` parser instead of the default `commons`?

UPDATE:

I don't know why that mocked data was working fine. Here's a closer representation of the data:

CSV (Just 1 header and 1 line of data...):

```
Digital ISBN,Print ISBN,Title,Price,File Name,Description,Book Cover File Name
97803453308,test,This is English,29.99,qwe_1.txt,test,test
```

Schema & the `spark.read` method:

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .schema(StructType(Array(
    StructField("Digital ISBN", StringType, true),
    StructField("Print ISBN", StringType, true),
    StructField("Title", StringType, true),
    StructField("File Name", StringType, true),
    StructField("Price", StringType, true),
    StructField("Description", StringType, true),
    StructField("Book Cover File Name", StringType, true)
  )))
  .option("quote", "\"")
  .option("escape", "\"")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .load(inputFilePath)
```

`df.show()` result in `spark-shell`:

```
+------------+----------+-----+---------+-----+-----------+--------------------+
|Digital ISBN|Print ISBN|Title|File Name|Price|Description|Book Cover File Name|
+------------+----------+-----+---------+-----+-----------+--------------------+
+------------+----------+-----+---------+-----+-----------+--------------------+
```

UDPATE 2:

I think I found "what's different". When I copy the data in the CSV and save it to another CSV, it works fine. But that original CSV (which was saved by Excel), fails... The CSV saved by Excel is 1290 bytes, while the CSV I created myself (which works fine) is 1292 bytes....

UPDATE 3:

I opened the two files mentioned in Update2 in `vim` and noticed that the CSV saved by Excel had `^M` instead of new lines. All of my testing prior to this was flawed because it was always comparing a CSV originally saved by Excel vs a CSV created from Sublime... Sublime wasn't showing the difference. I'm sure there's a setting or package I can install to see that, because I use Sublime as my go-to one-off file editor...

Not sure if I should close this question since the title is misleading. Then again, there's gotta be some value to someone out there lol...

Comment: I tested without schema and it works perfect. so can you share the schema?

Comment: `StructType(Array(StructField("Column One", StringType, true), StructField("Column Two", StringType, true), StructField("Column Three", StringType, true)))`

Comment: it works for me . what is the spark and scala versions you are working on?

Comment: @LXXIII Which spark version are you using? Because in Spark v2.3.0, your code works fine.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian 2.2.0. Granted, I simplified my code for this post. But now I realize, I should have tested this simplified code before posting, and if it worked, eliminate the differences until the real issue bubbled up. Okay. I've got some iterating to do haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question has a few up-votes, here's the resolution to the original problem as an answer...

Newlines in files saved in the Windows world contain both `carriage return` and `line feed`. Spark (running on Linux) sees this as a malformed row and drops it, because in its world, newlines are just `line feed`.

Lessons:

- It's important to be familiar with the origin of the file you're working with.
- When debugging data processing issues, work with an editor that shows carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with the option of multiLine being applied to the header. I solved it by adding the additional option for ignoring trailing white space.

```
  .option("header", true)
  .option("multiLine", true)
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", true)
```